# UIImageView and multi-threading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

In [What's New in iOS 4](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html), it is mentioned that `UIImage` drawing is now safe if done in a background thread.  However, when working with `UIImageView`, in most cases simple assignment to the image property:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]
```

is preferred over drawing for performance reasons (because `UIImageView` can make better use of GPU this way).

My question is: is assigning to `imageView.image` safe if done in a background thread?  In general UIKit requires work to be done in the main thread, so I am hesitant.

If it's not safe, what is the best way to make use of the fact that `UIImage` drawing is safe in non-UI thread when working with `UIImageView`?

Comment: If it isn't explicitly documented as being thread-safe, it isn't thread safe.   I'll leave a rendering expert to answer the actual question in your last sentence.